# Get the value from database in another page

Tags: php, html, mysql

Well, I got a mysql table, which is connected via vnesiUporabnika.php (through that file i insert the values in table) and is called in index1.php (my first page where the user register), than i have preveriUporabnika.php which is called in index1.php for log in verifying. And when user log in, my Stranzaindexom.html is loaded.

My table is called 'uporabnik' and my base is called 'spletnabaza'. My table got 5 coloumns (id, ime, priimek, uporabnisko, geslo). Coloumn uporabnisko and geslo are used in preveriUporabnika.php and vnesiUporabnika.php

Now on my Stranzaindexom.html i need to add a name from table coloumn 'ime'. But i need the name of the signed in person. How do i get it ? My login form on index1.php is just checking if user exist and doesnt make a new insert in table. So how can i get to the right name of user from database to show up here on Stranzaindexom.html ?

Any ideas?

Comment: And the code you tried is?

Comment: I havent tried any code yet, i am askig here for ideas, how to even start.

Comment: Throwing a bunch of presumably Polish(?) page, script and column names around is not very helpful in explaining what your actual problem is. Next time, please try to abstract this a little bit more, and use common English identifiers in your example/description, that are understandable to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I would make Stranzaindexom.html a PHP file (Stranzaindexom.php), this will allow you to only display that page if the user is logged in, by checking that their session exists.

e.g.

```
<?php
  if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    header("Location: login_screen.php");
  } else {
    // display page
    ....
  }
?>
```

The following link will help with your understanding of PHP sessions and User Authentication, it is a series of basic tutorials explaining each aspect:

http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php14p1.html

When you check that the username and password match in the database using a SELECT statement, you can select the name value from the 'ime' column.

i.e.

```
SELECT ime FROM uporabnik WHERE uporabnisko="example-user" AND geslo="password"
```

And either pass it to Stranzaindexom.php by attaching it to the URL (query string).

i.e.

```
Stranzaindexom.php?ime=Matej
```

Or set a session with the logged in user's name (this is my recommended method)

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['ime'] = 'Matej';
```

**NOTE:** If you insist on keeping Stranzaindexom.html as a HTML file, it would be possible to check logged in user session by communicating with PHP via AJAX, but this would over-complicate what you are attempting to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I'm on my way to change the file name. I'm still reading about php session, so when I'll finish I will do the modifications to my files/code. I'll let you know when I finish.

Comment: Sidenote: If OP is on Apache, can instruct Apache to treat `.html` files as PHP through `.htaccess`. (Good answer). ;)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe research starting PHP sessions and applying the user ID from your MYSQL table to a session variable.

Then you can use this in further queries to retrieve the info you want out of the DB.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Try attaching a session Variable when the user logs in on your index.php

Comment: Thanks, i'll take a look and try with sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Well You need to use session for this.

When you login through the username and password at that time for checking u need to fire select query and of course select return the data of the user if match or empty the result if it  not in db.

Once You have those data stored in session varibale like below:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = <value fetch from the select query>
```

And this variable is accessible to each page

Note: Dont forgot to put session_start() at very first line of your page.

For more details refer http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php